# JDBC - ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Jdbc {

    public static void main(String j[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Id:-");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "System", "Mohit");
            String sql = "insert into st values(id)";
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            boolean res = stmt.execute(sql);
            if (!res) {
                System.out.println("Value Inserted");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Value  Not Inserted");
            }
        } catch (Exception k) {
            System.out.println("Exception is:-" + k);
        }
    }
}
```

Here In My Code I want insert value in database but it throws me exception, while in Statement Interface we cannot Pass value Dynamically But we can Pass Value Manually

```
C:\Users\MOHIT\Desktop\PACK>java Jdbc
Enter Id:-0 0
Exception is:-java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Answer (score 3):

**About the error**

From the link [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00984_column_not_allowed.htm)

> An ORA-00984 will be thrown if a column name (like in the VALUES
>   clause of an INSERT statement), is used in an expression where it is
>   not permitted.  You may have used a column name in an expression where
>   it is not permitted.  Typically, ORA-00984 occurs while including a
>   column name in the VALUES clause of an INSERT statement.
>
> **To correct ORA-00984, you simply need to view the syntax of the SQL
>   statement and only use column names where they are appropriate.**
>
> You may also find it appropriate to include a character value, in the
>   INSERT statement, instead of the column name.

---

**Solutions**

If you look closer of your query then you find that the syntax is not correct here is the correct syntax of insertion :

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2);
```

If you want to pass all the column then you dont need to specify the columns names.

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2);
```

---

If your table contain only id then you can use :

```
String sql = "insert into st values(" + id + ")";
//---concat your id with your query-^--^-^----
```

If your table contain multiple columns then you can use :

```
String sql = "insert into st(id) values(" + id + ")";
//---------------------------^^-------------^^-------
```

---

**Note**

Statement can cause a syntax error or an [SQL Injection](https://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection) you have to use [PreparedStetement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

So instead you can use :

```
String sql="insert into st values(?)";
PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
insert.setInt(1, id);
boolean res = insert.execute(sql);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Query

when you say to the DB: "insert into st values(id)";
the db does not know what "id" is . It tries to guess that it is a column, since it is an element not enclosed in quotes, which means it is not a string value.

But there is not such column available at that time which is indicated by the raised Exception.

A way to do it is instead with prepared statement as stated by YCF_L. Also it is a good idea to always close the ResultSet (you don't have one here), statement, and connection.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Jdbc {

    public static void main(String j[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Id:-");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "System", "Mohit");
            String sql="insert into st values(?)";
            PreparedStatement psmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            psmt.setInt(1, id);
            boolean res = psmt.executeUpdate();
            if (!res) {
                System.out.println("Value Inserted");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Value  Not Inserted");
            }
        } catch (Exception k) {
            System.out.println("Exception is:-" + k);
        }
        finally {
            psmt.close();
            conn.close();           
        }
    }
}
```